# /data/sdext2 mount not found link2sd

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.3-gingerbread, mount, link2sd

I installed cm 7.2 stable (android 2.3.) frome [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=tass). Then i followed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1254987) guide to prepare my sd card for link2sd. Then i installed link2sd on my phone and created mount script for the ext2 partition. It generated fine and i rebooted the phone but still the ext2 partition was not mounted and it never gets mounted.
Root access is available to link2sd.
No error appears while mounting or creating script.
But when i try to create link for an app it says "/data/sdext2 not found".
How can i get my 2nd partition mounted. I have tried ext2,ext3,ext4 already.